# Where do you put 'modules: true' in next.config.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, babeljs, prismic.io

I have tried *everything* to get next-slicezone to work in my project, and support has told me to put 'modules: true' in my next.config.js file, but no matter *where* I put it, I still get this error:

```
C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\node_modules\next-slicezone\resolver.js:2
import { createResolver } from './features/resolver'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.next-slicezone/resolver (C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\pages\_document.js:103:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object../pages/_document.js (C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\pages\_document.js:21:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\pages\_document.js:223:52)
    at C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\pages\_document.js:224:115
    at Function.__webpack_require__.X (C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:108:21)
    at C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\pages\_document.js:224:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jrhag\react-sites\edit-elements\.next\server\pages\_document.js:227:3)
```

Here is my next.config.js file:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const withSvgr = require('next-svgr')
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images')

module.exports = withPlugins([
  withSvgr,
  [optimizedImages, {
    handleImages: ['jpeg', 'png', 'webp', 'gif']
  }]],
  {
    future: 
    {
      webpack5: true
    },
    modules: true,
  },
)
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "edit-elements",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 8888",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "slicemachine": "start-slicemachine --port 9999"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.31",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@prismicio/client": "^4.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.9",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "essential-slices": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^8.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebaseui": "^4.7.1",
    "framer-motion": "^3.1.1",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^9.0.0",
    "next": "^10.2.1",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "next-slicezone": "0.1.0-alpha.0",
    "next-svgr": "^0.0.2",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^6.4.1",
    "prismic-dom": "^2.2.5",
    "prismic-reactjs": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.3",
    "responsive-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.4",
    "slice-machine-ui": "^0.0.45",
    "storybook": "^6.2.9",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "theme-ui": "^0.7.3",
    "webp-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-require": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Here's my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-require"
  ]
}
```

Can somebody please help me troubleshoot this? Where do I specify 'modules: true' in the next.config.js file? Why am I getting this error when I've followed the next-slicezone documentation to the letter? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually node_modules is not included in the transpile process but is hard to tell for sure if this is the problem, can you try something like https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules to see if that is really the problem, if so next-slicezone should do a more robust build that cover more environments and not only esmodules.

Comment: So, next-transpile-modules *does* make it work, but people have said (even the creator) that it's a 'hacky' solution. It also doesn't mention anywhere in the docs that you *need* next-transpile-modules, so it's leading me to believe that it's a setting that I'm not doing correctly.

Comment: Yes, it was just to confirm that it was really the problem. So the creator of `next-slicezone` needs to generate a bundle compatible with not only es modules.

Because the current problem is that you have your transpiled version of next.js trying to use ES modules, so for that to be fixed you need to transpile your self (hacky solution as you said) or the package maintainer needs to consider this issue.

Comment: If you want you can customize your next.js with this: `exclude: /node_modules\/(?!next-slicezone)/,`. It should tell your webpack to ignore all node_modules packages except `next-slicezone`. This is where you do it: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

I hope that helps, there is nothing else I can think of 

Comment: Interesting. The docs don't mention this issue at all, and others are seemingly using it without this error, which is what led me to believe that it was a configuration error. I'm just not even sure how to troubleshoot this... :/

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work but you can try to set modules under the `preset-env` babel config but that is not recommended because you will lose code splitting as said in the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config in adition you can take a look into preset-env doc https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env